# Gradle Error: Duplicate files copied

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio, gradle

I'm having a problem during the packaging on gradle.

```
Error: duplicate files during packaging of APK /Users/rribas/Projects/sampleapp/samplea-app-android/app/build/outputs/apk/sampleapp-debug-unaligned.apk

Path in archive: values/attrs.xml
Origin 1: /Users/rribas/Projects/sampleapp/sampleapp-android-app/app/build/intermediates/javaResources/debug/values/attrs.xml
Origin 2: /Users/rribas/Projects/sampleapp/sample-app-android/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/pulltorefresh/classes.jar
```

Imagine that you have a root project 'app' that has some resources files (such as attrs.xml and strings.xml).

If you have a submodule library that has resource files (in this case attrs.xml and strings.xml) and include this same library into your build.gradle (using compile project(':submodules:pull-to-refresh'), you cant exclude one of the files, because you will need them in runtime.

Im facing this problem in my project.

**Here's the build.gradle file of pulltorefresh module:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['res']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
}
```

**Here's the main build.gradle of the project :**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['res']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }

    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'pt.sampleapp.gradle'
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 15
        versionName '1.4.1'
    }

    /*buildTypes {
        debug {
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
            proguardFile 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }*/

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }

    productFlavors {
    }
}

allprojects {
    android {
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Submodules
    compile project(':submodules:pull-to-refresh')
}
```

If i add another submodule that uses the same kind of file (such as values.xml) this kind of problem remains.

Comment: Hi guys! There was a misunderstood about JavaResources (resources.srcDirs) and android resources (res.srcDirs). 

I was telling gradle that resources.srcDirs would target res folder. That's why i saw the attrs.xml file in classes.jar and outside classes.jar after APK packaging. My bad guys!